# Текстурирование контура полигона

Tags: qt, opengl, графика

В моем картографическом приложении требуется рисовать линии границ полигонов сложным паттерном (текстурой).
Для этого я разбиваю полигон на сегменты, вычисляю угол между сегментами и рисую текстуру последовательно, пока сегмент не закончится. Вот что получается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, при низком уровне масштаба длина сегментов становится слишком малой чтобы вместить полностью хотя бы одну текстуру. Становится невозможным точно идентифицировать паттерн.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В похожем по своему функционалу приложении(с закрытым исходным кодом) данная проблема решается очень красиво. Текстура огибает весь контур, а не заполняет отдельные сегменты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу такую же реализацию, но не могу понять как это работает.

Я использую QPainter, т.к. плохо знаю OpenGL. Там же, скорее всего используются OpenGL и шейдеры. 
Но я хочу понять саму концепцию и попробовать реализовать с помощью QPainter-а. (тексту например, можно согнуть каким-нибудь отдельным алгоритм, но для этого надо понять в каком месте ее гнуть и на какой угол). А потом, может быть позже и OpenGL начну использовать.

Answer (score 1):

В OpenGL все делается очень просто - полоска из полигонов текстурируется UV картой с повторами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вероятно у вас в QPainter тоже есть какие-то инструменты работы с UV картами?